# Using autossh to port forward redis traffic on an unstable connection

Tags: ssh-tunnel, redis

**Setup**

1 redis master

3 clients redis slaves(for reads) with tunnels to master for writes

Each redis instance is a different server in a different location.

**Requirement**

Keep a persistent connection. When a slave disconnects be able to reconnect and resync with master as quickly as possible (< 1 minute).

**sshd on master**

TCPKeepAlive no

**autossh configuration file**

REDIS_SLAVE_PORT=6379
REDIS_MASTER_PORT=6379

AUTOSSH_FIRST_POLL=5
AUTOSSH_POLL=11

AUTOSSH_PORT=20000

AUTOSSH_GATETIME=10

AUTOSSH_LOGFILE=/home/xxx/autossh.log

AUTOSSH_PATH=/usr/bin/ssh

AUTOSSH_PIDFILE=/home/xxx/autossh.pid

AUTOSSH_LOGLEVEL=7 # FOR DEBUG

export AUTOSSH_POLL AUTOSSH_LOGFILE AUTOSSH_PATH AUTOSSH_GATETIME AUTOSSH_PORT AUTOSSH_PIDFILE AUTOSSH_FIRST_POLL AUTOSSH_LOGLEVEL

autossh -2 -fN -M ${AUTOSSH_PORT} -C -L ${REDIS_SLAVE_PORT}:localhost:${REDIS_MASTER_PORT} -i /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa user@master_ip

**each slave has own AUTOSSH_PORT 20000, 20002 20004 etc**

**Problem**

Usually when the connection between a slave and the master dies its re-established pretty quickly - autossh log:

> autossh[pid]: timeout polling to accept read connection
>
> autossh[pid]: port down, restarting ssh
>
> autossh[pid]: checking for grace period, tries = 0
>
> autossh[pid]: starting ssh (count x)
>
> autossh[pid]: ssh child pid is xxx
>
> autossh[pid]: check on child xxx
>
> autossh[pid]: set alarm for 5 secs
>
> autossh[pid]: execing /usr/bin/ssh
>
> autossh[pid]: connection ok

However, sometimes a different kind of disconnect seems to happen which won't reconnect even after 10 minutes of trying:

> autossh[pid]: 127.0.0.1:20000: Connection refused
>
> autossh[pid]: port down, restarting ssh

Only way I found currently to make it reconnect is to change the monitor port in the autossh configuration file by hand. This is not a good solution unless I can somehow automate it and free the port.

I tried to use inetd echo service on port 7 to find a workaround for monitor port(**-M 20000:7**) being in use, but for some reason that didn't work here is my autossh log from the attempt:

> autossh[pid]: not what I sent: "ubuntu autossh 10670 1817574984
> " : ""

and after that autossh dies.